# Why does my <ul> show up like this? (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make my website with Wordpress.
I wanted to add my custom horizontal menu, with plain CSS and HTML since plugins can't satisfy me.
This is my HTML code:

```
        <div id="provamenutop">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
        #provamenutop {background-color:#333; width:90%; line-height:100%;}
        #provamenutop li {position: relative; float:left; list-style: none; font-family:verdana;}
        #provamenutop li a {display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding: 20px; color: white; background: #333; transition:.4s;}
        #provamenutop li a:hover {background: #111;}
```

On my local computer, this looks right:
https://gyazo.com/d5b38f6cc1c7857dbe37945e2d8b5002

But here's what it looks like on my website, using a custom theme called Sportexx:
https://gyazo.com/5ccb7e944b627244a7d3ac8344471b28

I know this could be some CSS already existing in the theme interfering with mine, but what could I do to avoid the problem? (The space in between one Home button and the other is also clickable)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Check if there is a `li:after` CSS ruleset.

Comment: Try this `#provamenutop li {position: relative; float:left; list-style: none; font-family:verdana; margin: 0 !important;}`

Comment: [Don't use !important](http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/)

Comment: Make your CSS selectors [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: @MarioWerner There is a li:after, but it's in the widgets section.
for j08691: I don't know how to make this since I can only use ID selectors I guess. To be more specific I'd have to use a class selector or something else right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Chrome `Developer Tools` or Firefox `Firebug` and inspect the HTML, you will see the following output for your menu on the web site http://www.ferrari.co.it/athletic/

```
<div id="provamenutop">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><a href="#">
  </a><li><a href="#"></a><a href="#">Home</a></li><a href="#">
  </a><li><a href="#"></a><a href="#">Home</a></li><a href="#">
  </a><li><a href="#"></a><a href="#">Home</a></li><a href="#">
  </a><li><a href="#"></a><a href="#">Home</a></li><a href="#">
</a></ul><a href="#">
</a>
</div>
```

So the problem here is not CSS, but faulty HTML. You have two additional `<a href...></a>` tags. One before the `Home` and one **outside** the closing `</li>` tag and also one **outside** the closing `</ul>` tag.

If you fix your HTML, so that it looks like this, it will actually work:

```
<div id="provamenutop">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you, finally I got this fixed ^^
It definetly was a faulty html code, since I forgot to close the <a> tag... This was a noob mistake, but I hope I won't get through it anymore.

Comment: I'm curious @Mario -- for "you will see the following output" is that the DOM tree that was built (after the browser fixes invalid markup) or the view-source of what was actually received, prior to interpretation?

Comment: @StephenP It was the DOM tree I saw in my Chrome when right-clicking the menu and selecting "Inspect". AFAIK the browser doesn't necessarily fix bad markup.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a CSS conflicting issue.  Do you have a link so we can check it in firebug?  Should be a very easy fix.  When I run your html and css in JSFiddle it works fine.

> I'm not sure what you mean by On my local computer, this looks right: 
>   But here's what it looks like on my website, using a custom theme
>   called Sportexx:

Are you not using sportexx on your local computer?  If it's working without the theme and not working with the theme it's the CSS.  Just open up firebug in your browser and look at the css around the menu.  You should be able to adjust it right there and remove the problem.  Then go to your stylesheet and make the changes accordingly.

After seeing your comment.  It's the html.  Just delete the other links.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted. But without more info from the OP, this is the most correct answer so far. It is most likely a CSS problem and can be fixed without using `!important`. I don't know Sportexx, but in WordPress, some child theme CSS can conflict with its parent theme CSS sometimes. To avoid this, move the load order of your style.css to the bottom, behind all other CSS files, so that it gets loaded last.

Comment: Yeah exactly what you thought, by the way I'm modifying the style.css in the parent because, for a reason I don't know (but I already asked here on Stack Overflow), changes made to the child theme's style.css don't apply.
By the way, here's the link:
www.ferrari.co.it/athletic

Comment: So your code in firebug is showing a lot of <a href="#"><a/> in between the <a href="#">Home</a>  which is basically blank menu links.  The reason the white likes like the top of a castle under that menu is because they are blank links in between your home links.  Make sure your html is correctly structured like you have it above because for some reason there are a lot of  blank links in that menu